# way to display the data from a multi function meter

Tags: communication, rs485, datalogger, meter, modbus

I have a multi function meter and i want to collect the data and display it. My idea was to create a api for serial communication?? will the idea work or is there any other better way?? the meter uses modbus rtu rs485 protocol..

Comment: If the meter has a data port, then it is usually supplied with its own data cable and software...

Comment: No idea why you are asking, or what. It has a documented RS485 protocol. Use it.

Comment: RS485 is similar to RS232 but not the same you will need an adaptor, you can buy USB to RS485 adaptors relatively cheaply and it will appear on your computer as a COM (Serial) port.  Can't help you any further but the commands it understands should be described in the user manual that came with your meter.  If not there will be a separate programmers manual available to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to design your api to use the modbus protocol.  In windows computers you are usually using a utility or driver program to interface with the modbus rather than re invent the wheel and write the protocol yourself.  Your meter should have modbus register numbers to get the information you need.  Once you are successful in reading the registers-  designing how to display the information or log it is totally up to you.